# SQLite query across multiple tabels

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have some code for my python project(though this is a SQLite question) where I'm using SQLite to keep all game items.

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

c = conn.cursor()

def item_by_owned(owned):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM items  WHERE owned=:owned", {'owned': 1})
    return c.fetchall()

def print_inventory_names(inventory):
    for i in inventory: #print out the name(index[0]) of each item in inventory
        print(i[0])   

inventory = item_by_owned(1)

i = 0

print_inventory_names(inventory)
```

This works great if i were to put every item into the one table, I'd like to split my DB up though as below:
[DataBase Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68DVi.png)

Is there a way to search across multiple tables?

something like:
    SELECT * FROM items,items2  WHERE owned=:owned

Comment: There’s `UNION` but it depends on what exactly the table forms are and what information you want from them

Comment: Like joining tables? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Comment: I did google and try some of the JOIN commands but just got an error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: owned

Comment: Got this sorted with UNION.

SELECT * FROM items UNION SELECT * FROM items2 WHERE owned=:owned""", {'owned': 1})

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM items UNION SELECT * FROM items2 WHERE owned=:owned""", {'owned': 1})